# How to conditionally define methods in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a Rails app with:

```
class Player < AR
  has_many :playlists
  belongs_to :master
end

class Playlist < AR
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :master
end

class Master < AR
  has_many :players
  has_many :playlists
end
```

When a Player has a master associated with it, it should delegate its playlists to the Master. When it doesn't it should use its own playlists.

So this can be solved I think by simply overriding the association method:

```
class Player < AR
  has_many :playlists
  belongs_to :master

  def playlists
     return super unless master
     master.playlists
  end
end
```

But let's say I'm dealing with more than just playlists, but rather a bunch of different collection types, what I'd like to do is this:

```
class Player < AR
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :series
  has_many :categories
  belongs_to :master

  %i(playlists series categories).each do |collection|
    if master
      define_method collection do
        master.send(:collection)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So basically I want to override and delegate the existing association only if an association to master exists on the instance. The problem of course is that the code is defining a method on the class, and the class has no concept of "master" association, only the instance does. Is there a way to do this more elegantly?

I can put the conditional that checks presence of master inside the define_method call like this:

```
%i(playlists series categories).each do |collection|
  define_method collection do
    return master.send(collection) if master
    super()
  end
end
```

But I don't think that's much better.

Comment: I think your last block of code is fine from a Ruby metaprogramming standpoint.  I don't think you'll find something more elegant.  Note: From an `ActiveRecord` standpoint, overriding associations is likely to lead to pain regardless of how you implement it (for example, eager loading won't work properly).

Comment: Yes, your only way is to put master check into generated methods, because that's where it exists. And +1 to Nathan's comment.

Comment: I suppose eager loading still works, you just have to eager load `playlists` _and_ `master: :playlists`

Comment: That's interesting, I did not really think too much about side effects of overriding AR associations. Might have to consider doing this differently. Something to look into anyway, thanks Nathan.